# Midnight Commander show disk usage

Tags: disk-usage, mc

I am trying to use midnight commander (mc) to show disk usage of particular directories. I'm aware that I can use the command menu, but I need see individual directory sizes on the fly. I am using <kbd>ctl + space</kbd>, but it very quickly lists all the subdirectories/files in a popup which vanishes. As this popup with the disk usage vanishes it is not possible to see it. I am trying to use mc to find disk usage.

Comment: What is your *question* then?

Comment: Maybe give a try to `ncdu`, this is his main purpose.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Certainly! I have added some clarification.